# ROOM TypeConverter for a list of sealed class objects

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, moshi

I am having trouble using a typeconverter for a list of sealed classes. Here is my code:

```
class ContentTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun saveContentList(list: List<Content>): String {
        return convertObjectToJson(list)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun getContentList(list: String): List<Content> {
        return convertJsonToObject(list)
    }
}
```

```
val moshi: Moshi = Moshi
    .Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

inline fun <reified T> convertJsonToObject(json: String): T =
    moshi.adapter(T::class.java).fromJson(json)!!

inline fun <reified T> convertObjectToJson(objectData: T): String =
    moshi.adapter(T::class.java).toJson(objectData)
```

and here is my Content sealed class:

```
sealed class Content {

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    data class Image(
        @Json(name = "media")
        @field:TypeConverters(MediaTypeConverter::class)
        val media: List<Media>,
    ) : Content()

    data class Text(
        @Json(name = "text")
        val text: String,
    ) : Content()

    object Unknown : Content()
}

class MediaTypeConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun saveMediaList(list: List<Media>): String {
        return convertObjectToJson(list)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun getMediaList(list: String): List<Media> {
        return convertJsonToObject(list)
    }
}
```

AS a result my room table is not populated. I know its because of content because once commented out, everything works.

My question is, is the typeconverter for a list of sealed class objects the way I did? Or should it be something else?

p.s. I am using a PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory for the types there, hence it is a sealed class.

```
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideMoshi(): Moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(
            PolymorphicJsonAdapterFactory.of(Content::class.java, "type")
                .withSubtype(Content.Image::class.java, "image")
                .withSubtype(Content.Text::class.java, "text")
                .withDefaultValue(Content.Unknown)
        )
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
```

Comment: trying using the `@TypeConverters` at the `@Database` level (the line before), this increases the scope of the converters as per https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/TypeConverters

Comment: Oh thats a good improvement, thank you for that. Although it didnt fix my issue =(